# Sorting dictionary of lists based on first value in list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I need to return a dictionary of lists in descending order based on the first number in each list, for example:

```
{'key1': [2, 3], 'key2': [7, 7], 'key3': [5, 10]}
should return: {'key2': [7, 7], 'key3': [5, 10], 'key1': [2, 3]}
```

What I had originally was:

```
orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):(v,k), reverse=True))
```

when the values of the dictionary were simply numbers, but now that I have changed the value of the dictionary to be a list to contain 2 numbers, I'm not sure how to access and sort by the first number..

I'm using Python 2.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you test what you already had to see whether it still worked? Because it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you test what you already had to see whether it still worked? Because it does. When you sort a group of sequences, they are compared "alphabetically" - if the first items of two sequences are equal, their second items are compared, and so on. This means that, in your example, `sorted` would compare the first element of the value's `list`. If they are different, the sort order is exactly what it would be if you were comparing the first element only with `v[0]`. If they are the same, sorting by `v[0]` would simply ensure an arbitrary order for those elements. Leaving it as `(v,k)` ensures that if the first elements of the value `list` are equal, it sorts based on the rest of the elements. If there are two values with identical `list`s, it sorts based on the key.

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = {'key1': [2, 3], 'key2': [7, 7], 'key3': [5, 10]}
>>> orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):(v,k), reverse=True))
>>> orderedDict
OrderedDict([('key2', [7, 7]), ('key3', [5, 10]), ('key1', [2, 3])])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there!

```
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):v[0], reverse=True))
                                                               ^^^^
```

When `sorted(..)` is called with a `key=` argument, every element of the first parameter is passed to the lambda. In your case, `k` would be one key (eg: `"key1"`), and `v` would be one value (eg: `[7,7]`). All you need to say from here is: `v[0]`

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):v[0], reverse=True))
OrderedDict([('key2', [7, 7]), ('key3', [5, 10]), ('key1', [2, 3])])
```

---

**NOTE**: There is a difference between saying: `v[0]` and `(v[0],k)`. In the latter case, you are passing a tuple for comparison. It might not do what you'd want. Read up on how tuple comparison works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `v`, you have to just mention `v[0]` that is the is the index in value on which you want to sort.

```
>>> orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):v[0], reverse=True))
>>> orderedDict
OrderedDict([('key2', [7, 7]), ('key3', [5, 10]), ('key1', [2, 3])])
```

Additonal piece of info, you may remove `reversed=True` param in the call and replace `v[0]` with `-v[0]`. Result will be same:

```
>>> orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v):-v[0]))
>>> orderedDict
OrderedDict([('key2', [7, 7]), ('key3', [5, 10]), ('key1', [2, 3])])
```